# Сортировка 2D-массива по нескольким компонентам элементов

Tags: сортировка, javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть простой код на JS:

```
vals = vals.sort(
   function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]}
);
```

Он сортирует двумерный массив по второму значению его элементов. Но у такого решения есть один минус: если в массиве присутствует несколько одинаковых значений, которые идут подряд друг за другом, например {12, 13, 1, 1, 1}, они пропускаются функцией, и их необходимо сортировать по другому значению, т.е. по `a[0]`. Однако я совершенно не представляю, каким образом при помощи sort() можно реализовать такое, и можно ли вообще?..

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так:

```
vals = vals.sort(
   function(a, b) {return a[1]==b[1]?a[0]-b[0]:a[1] - b[1];}
);
```

Comment: Все гениальное просто, не подумал про это. Спасибо.